# Pass a complex list of models from Java to PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, data-structures, plsql

I am trying to pass a list of models to PL/SQL function

I have created two types like so

```
create or replace TYPE SPECIAL_TYPE AS OBJECT(
 SPECIAL_ID NUMBER,
 NAME VARCHAR2(4000),
 IS_ACTIVE NUMBER);
```

and

```
create or replace TYPE SPECIAL_ARRAY 
AS TABLE OF SPECIAL_TYPE;
```

I have defined model as following

```
public Class Special{

  protected long specialId;
  protected String specialName;
  protected boolean isActive;

     public long getSpecialId() {
        return specialId;
    }

    public void setSpecialId(long value) {
        this.specialId = value;
    }

    public String getSpecialName() {
        return specialName;
    }

    public void setSpecialName(String value) {
        this.specialName = value;
    }


    public boolean isIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean value) {
        this.isActive = value;
    }

}
```

In my DAO class I am trying to pass a list of models that defined above to PL/SQL procedure. In order to accomplish that I have the following code

```
Object[] listToPass=list.toArray();

ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "SPECIAL_ARRAY", conn );

ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, listToPass);
```

Once I get to the above line I get an exception that bean can not be converted to internal representation.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: Special [specialId=81, specialName=CHP, isActive=true]
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatum(OracleTypeADT.java:339)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeADT.java:372)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeUPT.java:108)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1321)
    at oracle.sql.ARRAY.<init>(ARRAY.java:141)
    ... 70 more
```

There is something small that I am missing but I can't figure out what. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a trailing space in `"SPECIAL_ARRAY "`; but which line is the error from, that `createDescriptor()` call or the `new ARRAY`?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a trailing space in my code just a typo here. Exception is thrown at ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "SPECIAL_ARRAY ", conn ); line

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is for your `Special` class to implement [SQLData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLData.html).

The implementation of the interface methods in your Special class would then be as follows:

```
    public String getSQLTypeName() { 
        return "SPECIAL_TYPE";
    }

    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.specialId = stream.readLong();
        this.specialName = stream.readString();
        this.isActive = (stream.readInt() != 0);
    }    

    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeLong(this.specialId);
        stream.writeString(this.specialName);
        stream.writeInt(this.isActive ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

You would also need to add the type to the [database connection's type map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getTypeMap()).  Do this whenever you get a database connection that may use your `SPECIAL_TYPE` type:

```
        Map<String, Class<?>> map = conn.getTypeMap();
        map.put("SPECIAL_TYPE", Special.class);
        conn.setTypeMap(map);
```